# Proof that $V^*$ is isomorphic to $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation, duality-theorems

In my notes for a linear algebra course there is proof that $V^*$ is isomorphic to $V$. However I am unclear on a few of the steps.

We begin by choosing a basis $B = \{v_1,...,v_n\}$ for $V$. We now that $V$ is isomorphic to $R^n$, so it suffices to show that $V^*$ is also isomorphic to $R^n$, i.e. it has a basis with $n$ elements.

We let $\phi \in V^*$ and we use the dual basis of $V$, $B^* = \{\phi_1, ... , \phi_n\}$ and show that there is a unique choice of coefficients $a_1,...,a_n$ such that:

$\phi = a_1\phi_1+...+a_n\phi_n$.

Given our choice of $\phi\in V^*$ we can pick $a_1 = \phi(v_1), ... , a_n = \phi(v_n)$

#### This is where I start to get lost. In the line above why can we pick our coefficients like that?

The proof continues as follows:

Now we compare $\phi$ to the map

$\hat{\phi} = a_1\phi_1 + ... + a_n\phi_n$

We have by definition that $\phi(v_j) = a_j = \hat{\phi}(v_j)$ and hence $\phi = \hat{\phi}$.

Then the notes state that we have shown that $B^*$ spans $V^*$.

#### Again I am confused here.

What's the point in comparing $\phi$ and $\hat{\phi}$, aren't they the same to start of with as we define them with the same coefficients? And how is showing that they are the same equivalent to showing that $B^*$ is spanning.

The proof continues to proof uniqueness of the coefficients.

Thanks.

Comment: I would probably have started like this. (I think your proof actually is doing the same, but you haven't defined the $v_i$ or $\phi_i$, so I'm not sure.) Take the standard basis $\{ e_i \}_{i=1}^n$ for $V$. Consider the set $\{ T_i \}_{i=1}^n$ with $T_i(v)=v_i$ for $V^*$. Then $T_i(v)=(e_i,v_i)$ where the brackets denote the Euclidean inner product. This is an isomorphism. To prove that, you need to do some work; in particular, you need to be sure that it is onto.

Comment: @Ian Why bring an inner product into play when this can be done over a general field where an inner product can't be defined?

Comment: I am not really asking for an alternative proof, just clarification on the one presented.

Comment: @MattSamuel It makes the isomorphism quite explicit. It is also exactly what happens in the Hilbert space situation (where you can't exploit the fact that the space is finite dimensional). You don't really need it to do the proof, but I think presenting it makes the situation clearer. I also suspect this is actually what the OP's proof is doing anyway.

Comment: @Ian but it restricts the result to fields where an inner product can be defined. It doesn't work over finite fields, for example.

Comment: @curo As I said I think this is actually what your proof is doing: you have a basis for $V$ (that you already know is a basis). You use it to build a candidate for a basis of $V^*$, which has a simple isomorphism with $V$. Then you check that this is actually a basis of $V^*$.

Comment: @MattSamuel I suppose it would be clearer to note that I'm not using any special properties of the inner product, even though I'm using a formula of the same "shape". Consider that $T_j(v)=v_j=\sum_{i=1}^n (e_j)_i v_i$ makes sense in $\mathbb{F}^n$ for any field. This happens to be $(e_j,v)$ in the Euclidean setting, but it makes just as much sense in any finite dimensional space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$The proof is really in two steps. First, one shows that in the expression for the element
$$
a_1\phi_1+...+a_n\phi_n
$$
of $V^{*}$, the $a_{i}$ are uniquely determined as $a_i = \phi_{i}(v_{i})$. This shows that the $\phi_{i}$ are *linearly independent*.

To show that the $\phi_{i}$ *span* $V^{*}$, then note that for any $\phi \in V^{*}$ we have
$$
\phi = \phi(v_1) \phi_1+...+\phi(v_n)\phi_n.
$$
This is because both sides coincide on the $v_{i}$, and thus on the whole of $V$.

Answer (score 0):

We do *not* know a priori that $\widehat{\phi}=\phi$. We have simply evaluated $\phi$ on the basis elements and used these coefficients to define $\widehat{\phi}$ as a linear combination of elements of the dual basis. While it is not hard to see that $\widehat{\phi}$ takes on the same values as $\phi$ by linearity, it is *not* immediate. The fact that such coefficients exist to express the element in terms of the dual basis is half what we are trying to prove. This is a proof that the dual basis spans the space. After that we need to prove linear independence.